# Saving xterm output to file

Tags: linux, ubuntu-22.04, xterm, iperf

Now I am doing mininet & iperf & gnuplot homework
After typing

```
mininet > xterm h1 h2
```

I got two xterm windows to run my server & client scripts

I want to save client-receivers TCP result into a file, and I have tried like below

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.2 -p 5566 -t 15 > tcp_output
```

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.2 -p 5566 -t 15 | tee tcp_output
```

But both of them does not work
Can anyone help?

Comment: I found a created file, command like below "iperf -c 10.0.0.2 -p 5566 -t 15 > /tcp_output"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
iperf -c 10.0.0.2 -p 5566 -t 15 --logfile iperf.log
```